# Query mysql database via python for the total count of last month, last week, specific date etc

Tags: python, mysql

I have an sql table with the below data:

```
select day, counter from table1 where day LIKE '%201601%';
+----------+---------+
| day      | counter |
+----------+---------+
| 20160101 |  125777 |
| 20160102 |   31720 |
| 20160105 |   24981 |
| 20160106 |  240366 |
| 20160107 |  270560 |
| 20160108 |  268788 |
| 20160109 |  254286 |
| 20160110 |  218154 |
| 20160111 |  250186 |
| 20160112 |   94532 |
| 20160113 |   71437 |
| 20160114 |   71121 |
| 20160115 |   71135 |
| 20160116 |   71325 |
| 20160117 |  209762 |
| 20160118 |  210305 |
| 20160119 |  257627 |
| 20160120 |  306353 |
| 20160121 |  214687 |
| 20160122 |  214680 |
| 20160123 |  149844 |
| 20160124 |  133741 |
| 20160125 |   82404 |
| 20160126 |   71403 |
| 20160127 |   71437 |
| 20160128 |   72005 |
| 20160129 |   71417 |
| 20160130 |       0 |
| 20160131 |   69937 |
+----------+---------+
```

I have a python script where i run by

`python myapp.py January`

The January variable includes the query below:

`January = """select day, counter from table1 where day LIKE '%201601%';"""`

What i would like to do is to have to run the script with different flags and get the script to calculate the sum for all of the days of the :

```
last month,
this month,
last week,
last two weeks
specific month.
```

At the moment i have different variables for the months of 2016, this way the script will become huge, i am sure there is an easier way to do this.

`cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute(eval(sys.argv[1]))
                display = cursor.fetchall()
                MonthlyLogs = sum(int(row[1]) for row in display)`

The point of this is that i want to see discrepancies between data. My overall aim is to display this data in php at a later date, but for now i would like for it to be written to a file, which at the moment it is being written to.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Incubator

Comment: sorry that was supposed to be 201601 etc. I am not looking to insert but to select. the problem is that i need the %201601% percentage signs to be included in the query too otherwise the result is 0.
For example the code with the normal code before any changes were made:
2016-11-27 09:43 The total count for:  January 4199970
after the change:
2016-11-27 10:43 The total count for:  201611 0

Comment: The when isn't really so important, lets say i run it on the first of every month for the last months total count. The data in the table is like this: 20160101 452
20160102  265
What i do is run all these dates in a loop and sum the output, which works, but like i've said before i would like to not have to enter the month and let the script insert the date.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start this question over, with a small data set and a desired result. My sense is that you're over complicating the problem

Comment: Perhaps you are right, sorry. Shall i make a new question or edit this one?

Comment: It's up to you. Personally, I'd go with an edit.

Comment: I will do, give me a few mins, hopefully you can help.

Comment: Done, have a look, hopefully this time it is more clear.

Comment: I seem to recall mentioning something about a desired result. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Note, it can be useful to provide smaller counter values on the basis that some people (including myself) find it easier to add 7 and 2, say rather than 210305 and 69937.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can get access to current month and year using datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime

currentMonth = datetime.now().month
currentYear = datetime.now().year
parameter = str(currentYear) + str(currentMonth)
```

Passing this parameter in your query should work.

For the second, you may define a function with a flag that when set to 1, will set parameter as above otherwise parameter's value will be sys.argv[1].

Comment: Hi, Sorry because i am a bit of a beginner to python, would you be able to show me the complete query parameter so that i could try it?